# Error mod_wsgi django

Tags: django, apache2

Saludos estoy intentando colocar django en apache tengo la configuracion de la siguiente manera:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.org
    ServerAlias www.test.org
        ServerAdmin pocholo199037@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/healthsys
    WSGIScriptAlias /var/www/html/healthsys/healthsys/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/html/healthsys/>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/logs/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

el error que me genera es el siguiente:

```
ene 07 00:47:18 diego-19 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
ene 07 00:47:18 diego-19 apachectl[24419]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
ene 07 00:47:18 diego-19 apachectl[24419]: WSGIScriptAlias requires at least two arguments, Map location to target WSGI script file.
ene 07 00:47:18 diego-19 apachectl[24419]: Action 'start' failed.
ene 07 00:47:18 diego-19 apachectl[24419]: The Apache error log may have more information.
ene 07 00:47:18 diego-19 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
ene 07 00:47:18 diego-19 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ene 07 00:47:18 diego-19 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Es la primera vez que intento publicar un proyecto de django con apache en ubuntu quiza alguna sugerencia o que estoy haciendo mal, nota no uso entorno virtual uso django instalado de manera global, me pase en el siguiente tutorial:

[Publicar Django con apache2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNBpdT0N8hw)

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Has podido solucionarlo?

Comment: no lo siento no he podido creo que debo crear el entorono virtual

Comment: Lo cierto es que en la documentación es a lo que hacen referencia, y a mi con entorno virtual me funciona sin problemas. No he probado nunca a incarle la ruta de la configuración global de python en donde debería ir la ruta del entorno virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo siempre uso entorno virtual, pero supongo que utilizando en entorno global funcione igualmente.

De momento creo que tienes un error en la línea WSGIScriptAlias
El formato sería así:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/healthsys/healthsys/wsgi.py
```

En este enlace puedes ver más detalles [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

Te recomendaría configurarlo usando el daemon mode con las directivas WSGIDaemonProcess y WSGIProcessGroup